# Disable or enable logs on the basis of flag

Tags: java, spring, logging, slf4j

I am disable the log of slf4j in my spring application by adding the below code in my **properties file**. The code is -

```
logging.level.org.hibernate=OFF
logging.level.org.springframework.beans.factory=OFF
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.context=OFF
logging.level.org.quartz=OFF
```

It hides all the logs which are in that package.

Now I want that I have some flag which enable or disable these properties all at one time on the basis of that flag. It means if the flag is ON then it disable the logs otherwise all logs are show.

Is this possible, if possible than how?

Answer (score 0):

Can quickly turn off all Log4J output using a below property in log4j.properties file

```
log4j.rootLogger=OFF
```